# Save images having target objects from 1 folder to another after detecting target and non-target objects from the frames

Tags: python

Images from 1st folder are getting repeated along with images from 2nd folder while saving to the destination directory

I have made the code to identify target and non-target objects from images and save the images having my target object to a folder. Below is my code

```
def target_non_target(input_frames_folder,model_file,output):

    if not os.path.exists(output):
        os.makedirs(output,exist_ok=True)

    count=0
    folders = glob(input_frames_folder)

    img_list = []

    for folder in folders:
        folder_name=os.path.basename(folder)
        print(folder_name)
        out_path = output +"\\" + folder_name
        os.makedirs(out_path,exist_ok=True)

        for f in glob(folder+"/*.jpg"):
            img_list.append(f)

        for i in range(len(img_list)):
            v1=os.path.basename(img_list[i])
            img_name = os.path.splitext(v1)[0]
            image = cv2.imread(img_list[i])
            orig = image.copy()

            image = cv2.resize(image, (28, 28))
            image = image.astype("float") / 255.0
            image = img_to_array(image)
            image = np.expand_dims(image, axis=0)


            print("[INFO] loading network...")
            model = load_model(model_file)


            (non_target, target) = model.predict(image)[0]

            if target > non_target:
                label = "Target"

            else:
                label = "Non Target"

            probab = target if target > non_target else non_target
            label = "{}: {:.2f}%".format(label, probab * 100)


            op = imutils.resize(orig, width=400)
            cv2.putText(op, label, (10, 25),  cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX,0.7, (0, 255, 0), 2)

            if target > non_target:
                cv2.imwrite(out_path+"/"+"\\{}.jpg".format(img_name),orig)
            cv2.waitKey(0)

    #return target_op


frames_folder = ("C:\\Python36\\videos\\videos_new\\*")

model = ("C:\\Python35\\target_non_target\\target_non_target.model")

output_folder = ("C:\\Python35\\target_non_target\\Target_images_new")

target_check = target_non_target(frames_folder,model,output_folder)
```

Suppose there are **2 folders A and B in 2 different drives like Drive C and Drive D**. Target images read from folder A of C Drive need to be saved in folder A of D drive. Target images from folder B of C Drive need to be saved in folder B of D Drive. This is working but **images from folder A of D drive are getting repeated in folder B of D Drive which should not happen**. Can someone guide me what changes shall be made for getting the desired results?

Answer (score 0):

Of course Python offers all the tools you need. To copy files, you can use shutil.copy(). To find all JPEG files in the source directory, you can use glob.iglob().

```
import glob
import shutil
import os
src_dir = "your/source/dir"
dst_dir = "your/destination/dir"
for jpgfile in glob.iglob(os.path.join(src_dir, "*.jpg")):
shutil.copy(jpgfile, dst_dir)
```

Comment: @ Shapa Nur Alam I don't want to copy all the images from 1 folder to other directly. I read the images from a folder,detect target or non-target images and then save the target images to a folder. Does your script perform the same?